# 22.04: language indicator doesn't represent currently selected language

Tags: keyboard, 22.04, gui, language-support

I have 3 languages in my system. The language icon in the top right corner should represent the currently selected one. Instead, it keeps being "EN" despite me switching the language; and the layout language actually switches, I just can't tell which it is based on the menu icon.

Comment: Does https://launchpad.net/bugs/1956916 apply to your case?

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Thanks, I'll read that thread and check if it has a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the tip from Gunnar Hjalmarsson, I was able to find the solution (https://launchpad.net/bugs/1956916). And although it's not ideal, there are multiple ways to deal with the problem.

1. Switching to a single key for changing layouts works perfectly, it switches them cyclically. (I'm sticking with `Caps lock` for now)
2. Running these commands overrides the original setting's limitation:
   `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-input-source "['<Shift>Alt_L']"`
   `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-input-source-backward "['<Alt>Shift_L']"`
   This method opens an popup with layout selection options (it appears for as long as keys are being pressed down). I didn't find it very useful if there are 3 or more layouts because quick tapping switches the layout randomly.
3. There are some comments that refer to `XORG` and `Impish` but I couldn't make out a specific solution. I still wanted to mention this in case previous 2 options are not satisfactory, to indicate what to look for.